# PCRE - Add quotes around patern

Tags: regex, pcre

I want add quotes around all matched patterns. Numbers, variable names, lenght of numbers etc. is various. Only format is this same but numbers can be decimals.

String:

```
interval = 14..12:5
jaja1 = 1
du =545
werfgbhnm=0.5..0.7:1
dasdsa = "false"
dasdsa2 = False
```

Pattern:

```
[-\d+\.]*\.\.[-\d+\.]*:[-\d+\.]
```

I want add substitution like:

```
 s/[ =][-\d+\.]*\.\.[-\d+\.]*:[-\d+\.]*/\"[ =][-\d+\.]*\.\.[-\d+\.]*:[-\d+\.]*\"/g
```

Result:

```
interval = "14..12:5"
jaja1 = 1
du =545
werfgbhnm="0.5..0.7:1"
dasdsa = "false"
dasdsa2 = False
```

Ofcourse my solution dont work. Replace my string with pcre pattern. How achive result like above?

Comment: Can you just provide a simple example of a string and the new string you want with replacement?

Comment: Done. I edited question.

Comment: Try [`=\s*\K\d+(?:\.\d*)+:\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/tWOoLz/1)

Comment: Its not substitution. Check edited question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
s/(\w+\s*=\s*)(\d+\.\.\d+:\d+)/\1"\2"/
```

see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ph9Elp/4).

This uses two capturing groups, and puts the second capturing group between quotes. In fact, I think no capturing groups are needed, try:

[`s/\d+\.\.\d+:\d+/"\0"/`](https://regex101.com/r/ph9Elp/5)

Comment: String where is 'interval=' is various. Only pattern format is always this same. Its reason why I wrote my pattern in question.

Comment: Ok then change `interval` with `\w+` and it should work. See https://regex101.com/r/ph9Elp/4

Comment: What if on end of variable name will be integer? or when someone wrote 'interval='? It should work will large amount of data. I will fix my question again.

Comment: Unfortunately its work only in regextester. In my perl script after substitution its looking like it:`interval = ""

[thresholds]
low = ""
high = 40
persistence = 9

[bbands]
TimePeriod = 20
NbDevUp = 2
NbDevDn = 2` its expression: `$substitute =~ s/[-\d+\.]*\.\.[-\d+\.]*:[-\d+\.]*/"\0"/g;`

Comment: Group-backtracking in Perl only accepts positive integers (so `\0` will not work), Does   `s/([-\d+\.]*\.\.[-\d+\.]*:[-\d+\.]*)/"\1"/g` work?

Comment: This same issue.`low = ""`

Comment: I believe you're missing the parenthesis around the pattern. First I had `s/pattern/"\0"/g` but it should be `s/(pattern)/"\1"/g`. Note  `(pattern)` must be enclosed in parenthesis.